# Defining the start and end point of a loop in bash

Tags: bash

I have a directory with folders sequentially numbered 1-1000, however I want to perform an action for some of the folders in this directory. i.e folders 1-50. How do I define the start and end point of the loop?

So far I have a script along these lines:

```
a=1
b=1

for i in ~/PATH/*/ ;do

(cd $i/ && action)

echo "completed"
a=`expr $a + $b`

echo "Next Folder"
done
```

I can define the start of the loop by changing a= but I am not sure how to define the end to the loop? As it stands, it will keep going through all the folders in that directory. Thanks :)

Comment: Look up `c-style for loop`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
a=1
b=1

cd ~/PATH/
for i in $(ls -v) ;do
  (cd $i/ && action) && echo "completed" || echo "error"
  a=$((a+b)); [ "$a" -gt 50 ] && break 
  echo "Next Folder"
done
```

Comment: That does the first 50 in the shell's glob expansion, but if the names are without leading zeros like `1 2 3 ... 9 10 11 12 ... 99 100 101 102 ... 999 1000` (which is not clearly seated either way) then the first 50 are `1 10 100 1000 1001 1002 ... 1046` which is not the requested 1-50.

Comment: I do a little modification to fix this.

Answer (score 8):

Using the command `seq` to generate the list over which to iterate:

```
for nn in $(seq 1 50) ; do
    (cd someprefix/$nn && action)
done
```

Or, if your shell supports [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

```
for nn in {1..50} ; do
    (cd someprefix/$nn && action)
done
```

Answer (score 5):

Bash allows for loops that looks like the standard C `for`-loop:

```
for (( i = 1; i <= 50; ++i )); do
  ( cd $i && action )
done
```

Change `cd $i` to `cd "$HOME/PATH/$i"` or whatever the path is to your directories.

Answer (score 4):

The `break` command allows you to break out of a loop.

So you would do something like this, after setting `a`

```
if [ $a -gt 50 ]
then
  break
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

You can even do a while loop instead:

```
a=1
while [ $a -le 50 ]; do
   (cd $a/ && action) 
   a=$((a+1))
done
```

Or, alternatively:

```
a=1
while (( ++a<=50 ));do
   (cd $a/ && action) 
done
```

Comment: OP said it starts on 1, so maybe `a=1`? Another while could also be `while (( ++a<=50 ));do`